# extract value from xml file using python based on keyword search

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am parsing an xml file using Python ElementTree/lxml (pydev).

EDIT: Complete xml file:

[[https://pastebin.com/embed_js/Gbrv9wgG]](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/Gbrv9wgG)

I am trying to extract all signalnames containing 'ROTARY' as the keyword in comment. The XML file contains many more 'PNIODEV's with or without 'CHANNEL' child.

Currently, I have all the comments printed out with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('Project.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
for comments in root.iter('COMMENT')
  print(comments.text)
```

I am unable to use lxml or elementtree to search only keyword 'ROTARY' in all comments and print corresponding Signalnames.
 I used the following code:

```
for word in root.xpath('.//CHANNEL[COMMENT[contains(text(),"ROTARY")]]"/COMMENT/text()'):
print (word)
```

Did not get any output...

Since I am new to Python and XML, any help will be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to `xml.etree.ElementTree` you can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse `XML` content.

This code will:

1. create a `soup` using the XML content
2. search for all occurrences of `<CHANNEL></CHANNEL>` tags
3. for each occurrence of `<CHANNEL>`, it'll search for the word `'ROTARY'` inside the `<COMMENT>` tag.
4. if it finds the word `'ROTARY'`, it'll print the value at `<SIGNALNAME>` tag.

**Example Code:**

```
s = '''<PROJECT>
          <HARDWARE CONFIGURATION>
             <PNIODEVICE>
                <PNIOSLOT>               
            <CHANNEL>
             <INDEX>2</INDEX>
             <SUBADR>0</SUBADR>
             <CHTYPE>E</CHTYPE>
             <MASK>4</MASK>
             <SIGNALNAME>ELE+S1-BGI51.2</SIGNALNAME>
             <COMMENT>ROTARY TRANSFER RADIAL ALIGNMENT 00SWIV</COMMENT>
             </CHANNEL>
            <CHANNEL>
             <INDEX>3</INDEX>
             <SUBADR>0</SUBADR>
             <CHTYPE>E</CHTYPE>
             <MASK>8</MASK>
             <SIGNALNAME>ELE+S1-BGI51.3</SIGNALNAME>
             <COMMENT>ROTARY TRANSFER RADIAL ALIGNMENT 1800SW</COMMENT>
             </CHANNEL>
            <CHANNEL>
             <INDEX>4</INDEX>
             <SUBADR>0</SUBADR>
             <CHTYPE>E</CHTYPE>
             <MASK>10</MASK>
             <SIGNALNAME>ELE+S1-BGI51.4_4C</SIGNALNAME>
             <COMMENT>ROTARY TRANSFER TRANSPORT ARM RIGHT 00R</COMMENT>
             </CHANNEL>
        </PNIOSLOT>
        </PNIODEV>
        </HARDWARE>
</PROJECT>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

channel_tags = soup.find_all('channel')

for channel in channel_tags:
    if 'ROTARY' in channel.comment.text:
        print(channel.signalname)
```

**Outputs:**

```
<signalname>ELE+S1-BGI51.2</signalname>
<signalname>ELE+S1-BGI51.3</signalname>
<signalname>ELE+S1-BGI51.4_4C</signalname>
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can bypass the `AttributeError` using a `try/except` statement.

```
for channel in channel_tags:
    try:
        if 'ROTARY' in channel.comment.text:
            print(channel.signalname)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you...I shall try it with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I'm sorry for not helping you with your `xml.etree` bug. I'm not that good with this library.. At least my code produces your desired output. :P

Comment: I get an empty array for find_all('CHANNEL') itself

Comment: what about `'channel'` ?

Comment: I got all the data except what is in between channel tags..But the error persists `if "ROTARY" in channel.comment.text:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`...sry I thought it was case sensitive :P

Comment: you can use a try/except clause and see if ti works... i'll add an edit in my answer

Comment: Works exactly as required! Thank you

Comment: I'm glad it worked! You can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output with using Etree only:
As stated here (And i would advice you to go through this documentation)- https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html: *Children are nested, and we can access specific child nodes by index*

So, you can do something like this:

```
for i in root[0][0][0]: # looping over CHANNELS
    if 'ROTARY' in i[5].text: # if 'ROTARY' is in COMMENT
        print i[4].text # print corresponding SIGNALNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [xml](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/Gbrv9wgG) contains invalid characters `&`, you can replace them with `&amp;`.
After fixing the xml, you can use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('xml_test.xml')
for channel in tree.findall('.//CHANNEL'):
    if channel.find('COMMENT') is not None:
        comment = channel.find('COMMENT')
        if comment.text is not None:
            if "ROTARY" in comment.text:
                print channel.find('SIGNALNAME').text
```

---

Output:

```
ELE+S1-BGI51.0_6C
ELE+S1-BGI51.1_6C
ELE+S1-BGI51.2
ELE+S1-BGI51.3
ELE+S1-BGI51.4_4C
ELE+S1-BGI51.5_4C
ELE+S1-BGI51.6
ELE+S1-BGI51.7
ELE+S1-BGI52.0
...
```

Comment: I have tried this...got this error: ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Pkg1\Py1.py", line 33, in <module>
    if  "ROTARY" in node.find(".//COMMENT").text:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'  `

Comment: Please post a valid xml in order to get proper help.

Comment: My xml file is pretty huge..So I was'nt sure of adding all the contents

Comment: I understand that, but select a block that contains all the opening and closing elements. You can also use https://pastebin.com/ to provide a full valid sample.

Comment: Thank you for the tip...I have attached the complete file

Answer (score 0):

Using XPATH

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree =ET.parse('Project.xml').getroot()
all_items = root.findall("HARDWARE/PNIODEVICE/PNIOSLOT/CHANNEL")
lines = [item.find('SIGNALNAME').text for item in all_items if 'ROTARY' in item.find('COMMENT').text]
print lines
```

EDITED : You have to specify that channel may have not a Comment tag !

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root =ET.parse('project.xml').getroot()
all_items = root.findall("HARDWARE/PNIODEVICE/PNIOSLOT/CHANNEL")
lines = [item.find('SIGNALNAME').text for item in all_items if item.find('COMMENT') is not None and 'ROTARY' in item.find('COMMENT').text]
print lines
```

Comment: Hi..I got the same error here too..`lines = [item.find('SIGNALNAME').text for item in all_items if 'ROTARY' in item.find('COMMENT').text]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`